# Validate only alpha characters, single/double quotes, space and comma in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, validation

So, I'm trying to validate a alpha char data type in an array with a function. If the array does not contain only alpha char and possibly symbols(single/double quotes, comma and spaces) log a message. I've tried working mainly with RegExp iterating through each element in the array first using !==. Also tried joining the array into a string first and validating against regex but doesn't seem to work quite right. Basically I would like the first array to validate uninterrupted and continue on to the rest of the script and array1 to log the message. This is kind of where I'm at, any help would be aces.

```
array = ['hello', 'hello'];
array1 = ['hello', 'hello1'];

var arrayChar = new RegExp(/[a-z',"\s]/i);

function validateArrayChar(array,char) {
  array.every(function(element) { 
    if (!char.test(element)) {
           console.log("Please re-enter data with valid letters.");
        }  
    });
}

validateArrayChar(array1, arrayChar);
```

Comment: You are trying to invert a regex in the constructor? You should compile the regexp object normally,then you may use `RegExp#test()` with `!` operator to see if there is a match or not. And do not use `g` flag with the regex used in `.test()`.

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming, I made an edit, would that be more inline? I'm still not getting the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot invert a RegExp by using a `!` in the constructor. Simply try this:

```
array = ['hello', 'hello'];
array1 = ['hello', 'hello1'];

var arrayChar = new RegExp(/^[a-z',"\s]+$/i); // This means the string must contain only what is between brackets, at least 1 character.

function validateArrayChar(array,char) {
  return array.every(function(element) { 
    return arrayChar.test(element);
  });
}

console.log(validateArrayChar(array1, arrayChar)); // Will return false, at least one character is invalid
console.log(validateArrayChar(array, arrayChar)); // Will return true
```

For Regex reference: https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, although this doesn't seem to be logging the message when validateArrayChar(array1, arrayChar); ? Copied the code exact into the editor.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code and the Regex because I did not remember that `every` expects all elements to return true in order to return true itself.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for validation, and I just made an extra function to display the message depending on the Boolean. Cheers.

Comment: Excellent. I think both answers would work, if you feel one did the trick please select it as the answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arrow function to do it in a shorter way.

**UPDATE.** I changed the regex cause if you put underscores in the string, the test returns `true`.

```js
var array1 = ['hello', 'hello'];
var array2 = ['hello', 'hello1 \'world\"'];
var array3 = ['hello', 'Hello_'];

var arrayChar = new RegExp(/^[a-z0-9,'"\s]+$/i);


var validateArrayChar = (array, validator) => {
  return array.every(element => validator.test(element));
}

console.log(validateArrayChar(array1, arrayChar));
console.log(validateArrayChar(array2, arrayChar));
console.log(validateArrayChar(array3, arrayChar));
```